# when I use a tuple for a key of a dictionary, can I search data with only one element of the tuple key?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Let's assume that there's a dictionary variable 'dict' like below. with tuple type keys in this case.

```
      dict = {(a,2019): 6, (a,2020): 7 , (a,2021):8, (a,2022):9, (b,2020):8, (b,2021):10}
```

And then I want to search all values with keys that has 'a' for the first element of the key.
So after search I want to put the result set into a list 'result'. result will have the values like below.

```
      result = [6,7,8,9]
```

I would be able to get values like below

result.append(dict.get((a,2019)))

result.append(dict.get((a,2020)))
....

but  I wanted to search data by matching only once  for example using regex in this case like

result=dict.get((a, "\d{4}"))
Obviously, this doesn't work.

I just want to know if there's a way that I can search data by matching only one element of tuple type keys in this case.

Comment: Sure: loop over the keys & test each in sequence.

Comment: What is `a`? A variable with some value I presume? If you are thinking the character `a`, then put `"a"` in the example, it makes it easier.

Comment: This is basically a double index. Is this a one-time lookup or do you want to index it once and use it multiple times?

Comment: Only by iterating through the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a list comprehension to see if a is in the key of you dictionary?

```
mydict = {(a,2019): 6, (a,2020): 7 , (a,2021):8, (a,2022):9, (b,2020):8, (b,2021):10}

result = [v for k,v in mydict.items() if a in k]
# [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just want a dictionary of dictionaries.  If you define:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(dict)
```

Then you can write things like `mydict['a'][2010] = 100` and have what you expect.

Looking at the value of `mydict['a']` will returns dictionary of all years in which the first part of the key is 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
dct = {('a',2019): 6, ('a',2020): 7 , ('a',2021):8, ('a',2022):9, ('b',2020):8, ('b',2021):10}

result = [v for k, v in dct.items() if k[0] == 'a']
print(result) # [6, 7, 8, 9]
```